# How to avoid shadow apply to a rich_marker in Gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Recently I've managed to dael with RichMarker and Gmaps4rails gem! Thanks to Apneadiving!
But now there is a nasty shadow that I cant remove.
tried

`:shadow_picture => " "`

and
It even seems not to be in the CSS.
And tried to do like it is told in [wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers)
like

`:marker_anchor => [10, true]`

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the doc but didn't push the code...

Install `v0.11.1` and use your correct code: `:marker_anchor => [10, true]`

Comment: Insane!!! I`ve done this by css `!important` it was junk. Now i`ll try it new way. BTW i have an arrow on the bottom of the marker how to set an offset for marker html to be placed?  Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Hoe can this be done in CoffeeScript? Which attribute do I set? `marker.setAttribute(...?)`